# Reference between two ecore

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I have A.ecore in which I created classes and ORBAC.ecore in which there is rules and permissions classes

How can I make a reference so that a class from A.ecore can refer to class permission from ORBAC.ecore

Answer (score 2):

Using the Ecore editor, open A.ecore
then right click, Load Resource...

you will have the possibility to load ORBAC.ecore (Browse Target Platform package, Registered Packages, File system or Workspace)

Once loaded, you'll be free to make references to classes defined in ORBAC.ecore.

Please note that the whay you load the additional resource may have some impacts when deploying your metamodels (and containing plugins). This is because Eclipse will use different URI scheme.  (platform:/resource/..., platform:/plugin/...,  registered nsUri, ...)

Comment: Thank you very much Didier for your help.
Actually I was able to build that reference between 2 ecore models but my problem now is that the value reference itself is empty when it is supposed to show me a list of input even though I made sure that I loaded the right model to my resource instance of the meta model that I have already created.

Do you have any idea why the value section of a reference [1,1] is empty ?

Thanks again.